# Laravel 5 | PHPUnit Testing Error

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-5

I just wanna to get the Status Code of the link(Path).

[I use Auth too]

MY INPUT :

```
public function testPath()
{
    $this->withoutMiddleware();
    $this->call('GET', '/admin/create');
    $this->assertResponseStatus(200);
}
```

Even i check this on Browser, I get proper response.
But in PHPUnit testing, i get the following error...

```
1) ItemsTest::testPath
   Expected status code 200, got 500.
   Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200
```

What is Wrong with my testing code...?

Comment: Try `$this->visit('/admin/create');` instead of `$this->call('GET', '/admin/create');`

Comment: K...Then how could i check its statuscode....

Comment: $cont = $this->visit('/admin/create');
        $cont->assertResponseOk();

I Get Same Error...

Comment: Did you set your route?

Comment: Yep...
I Solved that....Issue is happened by Validation Error Variable...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the Solution.

Actually i have some validation mistake on my view file.

Validation $errors variables initially undefined, so in PHPUnit test case consider this as Error.

So it returns 500 Internal Server error for me...